# How to make a proxy using a php script?

Tags: php, http, proxy, curl

Let's say i got a vps hosting with a dedicated ip, can i make a curl php script that receives a url, fetch it, and output it, and make all this as a proxy server, so i can put my vps ip in the proxy settings of the browser.

Is there any way to do that?

Note: Please don't suggest me a web based proxy like glype.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could (see Jasper's answer).  That would be effectively making your own web-based proxy.

However, given that it's a VPS, I would suggest using a SSH SOCKS proxy, since it'll be easier and will be running through an encrypted tunnel to the VPS.

Comment: As pointed out at my answer, I wasn't answering the question, so I removed my answer, leaving a dangling pointer at your answer.

Comment: There are the 3 types you can use.
1- web proxy (a web interface), wich is http proxy. // the usual WEB
2- http proxy, a program, a clean http protocol proxy // the usual one
3- socks proxy (v4/5), a raw socket connection. // powerfull, harder

Tor in fact is a socket proxy, but with more involved.
More on my answer. Thx for ask that.

Answer (score 1):

Use Apache with `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_http`. See the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html).

You can access the proxy through https, effectively encrypting all your traffic between your computer and the VPS.

Comment: Thanks, so what port should i put in the settings if i added mod_proxy to htaccess?

Comment: @David You can't put it in .htaccess It has to be in `httpd.conf` or some file included there. The port is arbitrary.

Comment: mod_proxy_http is to use a reverse proxy (cache proxy) that runs from apache's to "that server". It can be nginx, varnish, polipo, haproxy or many others.

This is not to create a vnc server, is to request the apache itself queries from another proxy installed on the machine or also in remote machines. (a la cloudflare style). That improves security layer and maybe dummy cache data for all the people :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use tor proxy, here is the script:

```
<?php
function tor_new_identity($tor_ip='127.0.0.1', $control_port='9051',$auth_code='saad'){
$fp = fsockopen($tor_ip, $control_port, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) return false; //can't connect to the control port

fputs($fp, "AUTHENTICATE $auth_code\r\n");
$response = fread($fp, 1024);
list($code, $text) = explode(' ', $response, 2);
if ($code != '250') return false; //authentication failed

//send the request to for new identity
fputs($fp, "signal NEWNYM\r\n");
$response = fread($fp, 1024);
list($code, $text) = explode(' ', $response, 2);
if ($code != '250') return false; //signal failed

fclose($fp);
return true;
}

?>
```

Call the function "`if (tor_new_identity('127.0.0.01', '9051')) {//do stuffs here}`"
But you must install the tor system in the VPS 1st.

Comment: This script is a socket wrapper for the http connection. Thats nice and can be used to tunnel to another socks proxy. TOR is a socks proxy.
I guess it won't open a browser to type the proxy. Him wanna configures the proxy at the browser, dont?

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong at what are you asking. You ask about PHP script, but don't like the Glype. There are at least 4 more PHP's proxy developments.

1. GlypeProxy, the most known PHP proxy. Does cURL.
2. Poxy, i discover it recently, love. Uses client/server sockets.
3. php-proxy, but there are few ones that shares that name // too basics

But in fact, no one will let you connect your browser with it, because you need to implement the tcp wrapper for the connection. This is the way you got usually an http interface with cURL or direct raw socket.

You need an SO app, not an script.

I would recommend you Squid proxy for Linux (handy and clean manual http://es.kioskea.net/faq/613-instalar-un-servidor-proxy-http-squid)
I would recommend you to not use Windows (even if i do), but the FreeProxy is awesome. (download at http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Proxy-Servers/FreeProxy.shtml)

On the other hand of the proxy, you got the VPN.
It's better and easier to install and connect to a VPN, a private SSH protected private network to your VPS. That will bypass ALL the traffic from your computer through a encrypted connection to/from the VPS.

You will have the VPS's IP, and "local" connectivity to your VPS/Desktop from both sides. (example, web servers with no need of open ports except the VPN one)

Answer (score -1):

You can check out [this PHP proxy that uses cURL](http://code.google.com/p/php5rp/).  It's not perfect (I'm in the process of fixing it to handle PUT requests, application/json POSTS, etc).  The thing is you'll need to configure the web server to rewrite all requests to this file's file name so you can proxy them properly.